# How to align multiple radio button lists?

Tags: css, asp.net, user-interface, radiobuttonlist

I have a set of radio button lists like this:
[image: What I have now]

But I'd like them to be like this instead:
[image: What I want]

Please note that these are asp radio button lists. How should I apply styling to get the expected result?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ASP is generating HTML, look at the source of your web page and grab/post the relevant code.

Comment: did you try anything!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the following CSS:

```
.radioButtonList
tr td { width: 100px; }
```